# How can I setup Gramex scheduler on first monday of month and first monday of a quarter?

Tags: scheduler, gramex

I tried this piece of code but it sends for every Monday every month or quarter. How can I restrict it to only the first Monday?

```
schedule:
  email-alerts-monthly:
    function: mymodule.check_email_alerts()
    weekday: mon
    months: '*' 
    utc: true

email-alerts-quarterly:
    function: mymodule.check_email_alerts()
    weekday: mon
    months: 'jan, apr, jul, oct' 
    utc: true
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code looks fine, check the timezone of the server you are running this application in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first Monday, add `dates: 1-7`. That will skip all subsequent weeks in the month, and still run it only on the first Monday.

```yaml
schedule:
  email-alerts-monthly:
    function: mymodule.check_email_alerts()
    dates: 1-7
    weekday: mon
    months: '*' 
    utc: true

email-alerts-quarterly:
    function: mymodule.check_email_alerts()
    dates: 1-7
    weekday: mon
    months: 'jan, apr, jul, oct' 
    utc: true
```